# how to multiply all entries in an excel column by a number

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with huge column size. I want to operate upon the column (no copying to a blank column) and multiply all the entries in that column by 1000, replacing the previous entries. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And you're working with some type of programming language...or with Excel alone?

Answer (score 10):

Here is the solution for you.

All you need to do is write a value in a cell, copy that and then use `paste special` option.

[How to multiply a range cells by a number in Excel?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/697-multiply-excel-cells-by-a-number.html)

Answer (score 5):

you can put the number that you need to multiply for in an other cell, for example in the image is B1, then create an other column multiplying the first number (image is A2) by the one in B1, but put the formula with $B$1 instead of B1, that will keep B1 value static, then drag the formula down and that is it, a new column with all entries multiplied by B1.

[image]

Comment: Excel 2010, give as error for $B$1. It only accepts B1. This only applied to 2013 version.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Multiply-a-column-of-numbers-by-the-same-number-aeb8a7d5-bcbc-486e-b1f8-dbbdf355d7d1
sorry,  It does not allow me to remove my down vote. You answer is actually quite helpful.